# How use multiple java scripts in HTML layout page

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the below error while loading my web pages:

Argument 'channelsAppController' is not a function, got undefined

I have 2 different web pages and one Layout page which includes 2 different java-script files:

```
<script src ="/Scripts/Views2/Channel.js"></script>
<script src ="/Scripts/Views2/Channel_Create.js"></script>
```

Here is the begging of each scripts:

Channel.js

```
(function() {
  var myApp;

  myApp = window.angular.module("myApp", []);

  myApp.controller("channelsAppController", function($scope, $http, $compile) {
```

Channel_create.js

```
  (function() {
  var myApp;

  myApp = window.angular.module("myApp", []);

  myApp.controller("channelCreateController", function($scope, $http, $compile) {
$scope.Channel = {
```

When I load either of the pages I get the error mentioned earlier.

If I comment out one of the scripts in the layout the page...the page  that doesn't uses the script loads and doesn't generate an error.

Each page has their respective controller specified in the root div.

I'm trying to figure out whats causing the errors:

How can I include multiple javascript files in a layout page while using angular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel.js

```
(function() {
  var myApp;

  myApp = window.angular.module("myApp", []); //Module definition

  myApp.controller("channelsAppController", function($scope, $http, $compile) {
```

Channel_create.js

```
  (function() {
  var myApp;

  myApp = window.angular.module("myApp"); //Module retrieval.

  myApp.controller("channelCreateController", function($scope, $http, $compile) {
$scope.Channel = {
```